# Have a txt file keep it's line breaks after being send over FTP via Curl

Tags: ftp, curl, newlines

I'm using Curl to send a file over FTP.  It is just a generated text file from a screen hardcopy command.  When I cat the file, it displays correctly, it looks like this:

```
System up for    14844
 1, 0000, R D S, 0, 0, x, 0.00
 2, 0000, R D S, 0, 0, x, 0.00
 3, 0000, R D S, 0, 0, x, 0.00
 4, 0000, R D S, 0, 0, x, 0.00
```

However when I look at the transferred file, it is all on 1 line.  Any way to fix this? Is there a command line option?  This is my curl command:

```
curl -T ~/hardlog.log ftp://10.0.0.7 --user user:secret
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you viewing the file on the same OS? I asked because usually you get these symptoms when a file gets transferred without any changes (you can check this, their MD5sums should be the same). However your client displays the text differently. This can happen if you transfer a file from a unix like OS (which uses linefeed at the end of a line to start at a new line) to a windows or DOS like OS (which requires both LF **and** CR).  [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) has more information on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was already mentioned this is a classical symptom of incompatible line endings. In this case the source system is Unix-like (Linux) and the destination is Windows-like. In Windows the Unix newlines are not recognized so the text file appears as a single long line. In such cases you should do a newline conversion.

Though the FTP protocol has the newline conversion built-in *Curl* does not support it even if forcing ASCII transfer using `-Q '+TYPE A'` option.

The most convenient option would be to do the conversion on Linux before the transfer using a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
SRCFILE=~/hardlog.log
DSTLOGIN=user:secret
DSTURL=ftp://10.0.0.7/              # the URL must end by a slash

unix2dos <"$SRCFILE" | curl -T- "$DSTURL$(basename "$SRCFILE")" -u"$DSTLOGIN"
```

If the `unix2dos` utility is not available on your system, you can use `sed 's/$/\r/'` or `awk '{printf("%s\r\n",$0)}'` instead. See [Alternatives to unix2dos conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos#Alternatives_to_unix2dos_conversion).

Another option is to use a client supporting ASCII transfers like *LFTP*. Example:

```bsh
lftp -e "put -a $HOME/hardlog.log ; exit" -u user,secret 10.0.0.7
```

**Note:** On Windows there are text editors capable of working with Unix newlines like *Wordpad* or some third-party ones: *Notepad++*, *Notepad2*. The last two editors can be also used for newline conversions.

Comment: Excuse me. From further research it seems that [*Curl* does not support the text file transfers](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/todo.html#ASCII_support). Please let me know if my example above does not work by chance. I will adjust the reply accordingly. I can also recommend you some standalone newline conversion tools which could be run from a script together with `curl`.

Comment: Thanks for this, you're correct (as was Hennes above) that I'm going from Linux to Windows.  I tried your code and unfortunately the newlines weren't formatted correctly.  I do have Notepad++, but as I'd like to automate the processing of these files, it would be nice to find a way to prep them beforehand.

Comment: @McB Thank you for feedback. I added other options to the reply.

Comment: Thanks for this!  lftp would be handy, but I'm actually working on a BeagleBone and it isn't available.  Since I'm trying to automate some of the setup process, downloading and making the file (which is possible) isn't ideal.  I don't have unix2dos either, but I tried this code which worked:

awk '{printf("%s\r\n",$0)}' hardlog.log > doslog.log

Answer (score -1):

Here's a crude but effective  little loop that adds a newline to the end of each line of text in a file.

```
    today=`date +%m%d` # file name filter
    for file in *${today}*
    do
      > ${file}.tmp
      while read readline
      do
        echo -e "$readline\n">> ${file}.tmp
      done <${file}
      cp ${file}.tmp ${file}
      rm ${file}.tmp
    done
```

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: This one. If we need to add dos line feeds to the file that quick script will do it.